# How to get background image working in webmail outlook web?

Tags: html, email, outlook-web-app

I am trying to build an email template. However I have a background image that is not showing up in the Outlook Web i.e. in the webmail. :( :(

I can not seem to figure out how to get that working for webmail. Does anyone know how to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of googling and hours wasted, realized that OWA does not support background image in normal mode. But when opened in full view, the image shows up. Beats me !

Answer (score 0):

`background-image` is not supported in outlook.com or outlook 2007/10/13.

Source: [The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

I suggest using something like [Bulletproof background images](http://backgrounds.cm/) that provide a fallback color. Otherwise, if you have to have a background image, you will need to slice the text with background images and use `img` tags.

Comment: I was able to get it working for most clients including 2007/2010/2013 using the bulletproof background image technique. But, it fails in OWA aka webmail. It is documented here http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/252644.aspx  . But I am wondering if it is even possible to target OWA using some kind of conditional statement so that atleast I can make it look better?